# VSCode editor: not seeing Git merge difference in file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

So I'm testing git merging and something weird happens.

I basically created a new file in master called test.txt.

- I created and switch to a branch called `test`.
- Add text "test branch" and commit
- Then I switch back to master branch, add text "master branch" and commit.
- Then switch back to test and do `git merge master`.

Terminal output is as expected.
[image]
However, when I open vscode and try to resolve the problem, I could only see it denotes there's a conflict but without anything such as "`incoming changes`".

View in normal editor:
[image: view in normal editor]

Changed in master branch:
[image: changed in master branch]

Changes in test branch:
[image: changes in test branch]

I didn't want to attach the files initially, since many may be concerned about virus. However, I couldn't find any other way to replicate this problem. So I would do that. My apologies in advance. Maybe opening this in a sandbox is a good idea. But I don't expect many replies really, it's a bit too demanding. (This zip file is evolved from Mosh's git class. Don't know if I can paste the link here lol)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKLm3cql5jbo7uyJWsUx6YHIamWbWjA8/view?usp=sharing

This problem only occurs on this particular project. So it wouldn't influence much. But I feel it's good to know why this happens. Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than "some changes"?

Comment: Your issue here is purely with how to use the vscode merge resolvers, and not actually anything to do with Git itself.

Answer (score -1):

By double-clicking on the test.txt file which has the `!` indicator, it should open it with the merge conflicts decoration (Current changes / Incoming changes)

That would be the first `test.txt` on the left side of the editor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I did what you said and that didn't quite work. It seems the git repo is malformed. If you'd like, you can check the zip file attached. But I don't expect much... It's totally fine if you feel unsave.

Comment: @Coding-pupupu OK. I don't have access to your file right now.